# JSON-запрос возвращает мне 0

Tags: python, json

**Мой метод:**

```
def randomAnime(id):
  try:
    if read_json(get_path(id), "action") == "liked_anime":
      anime_id = random.randint(1, all_anime)
      url = 'https://shikimori.org/api/animes/' + str(anime_id)
      
      headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'From': 'supp.dumb.anime@mail.ru'
      }

      r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      getJson = json.loads(r.text)
      name = getJson[0]['russian']
      keyboard = keyboard_like();
      sendMsg(id, name, keyboard)
      print (name)
    else:
      sendMsg(id, errorText, keyboard)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Проблема в том, что если моя программа делает запрос на json-файл без ошибки,** **пример:**

```
{"id":10000,"name":"Esper Mami Special: My Angel Mami-chan","russian":"Мами-экстрасенс: Спецвыпуск","image":{"original":"/system/animes/original/10000.jpg?1617269513","preview":"/system/animes/preview/10000.jpg?1617269513","x96":"/system/animes/x96/10000.jpg?1617269513","x48":"/system/animes/x48/10000.jpg?1617269513"},"url":"/animes/10000-esper-mami-special-my-angel-mami-chan","kind":"special","score":"0.0","status":"released","episodes":1,"episodes_aired":0,"aired_on":"1988-12-27","released_on":null,"rating":"pg_13","english":[null],"japanese":["エスパー魔美スペシャル マイエンジェル魔美ちゃん"],"synonyms":[],"license_name_ru":null,"duration":23,"description":null,"description_html":"\u003cdiv class=\"b-text_with_paragraphs\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","description_source":null,"franchise":"esper_mami","favoured":false,"anons":false,"ongoing":false,"thread_id":null,"topic_id":null,"myanimelist_id":10000,"rates_scores_stats":[{"name":10,"value":1},{"name":9,"value":1},{"name":6,"value":1}],"rates_statuses_stats":[{"name":"Запланировано","value":21},{"name":"Просмотрено","value":3},{"name":"Смотрю","value":1},{"name":"Брошено","value":24},{"name":"Отложено","value":3}],"updated_at":"2021-07-27T21:06:45.484+03:00","next_episode_at":null,"fansubbers":[],"fandubbers":[],"licensors":[],"genres":[{"id":4,"name":"Comedy","russian":"Комедия","kind":"anime"},{"id":31,"name":"Super Power","russian":"Супер сила","kind":"anime"},{"id":37,"name":"Supernatural","russian":"Сверхъестественное","kind":"anime"}],"studios":[{"id":247,"name":"Shin-Ei Animation","filtered_name":"Shin-Ei","real":true,"image":"/system/studios/original/247.png?1510312671"}],"videos":[],"screenshots":[{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/7c01c67c1daa1cd0c3b852b1aa6b57cef3584e6e.jpg?1595001666","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/7c01c67c1daa1cd0c3b852b1aa6b57cef3584e6e.jpg?1595001666"},{"original":"/system/screenshots/original/ac738ea3e2920d6f730707f7e7dbfa17455b36eb.jpg?1595001667","preview":"/system/screenshots/x332/ac738ea3e2920d6f730707f7e7dbfa17455b36eb.jpg?1595001667"}],"user_rate":null}
```

**Я получаю из:**

```
 except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**вывод в консоль: 0**

**Подскажите, что мне делать. Также я заметил, что код, включительно с этой строкой, перестает работать (скорее всего, что проблема именно в ней):**

```
name = getJson[0]['russian']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш json файл содержит единственный элемент, а не массив элементов, попробуйте обращаться напрямую к `['russian']`

```
name = getJson['russian']
```